# Responsive menu on mobile disappears on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to build a responsive site and am having some difficulty with the mobile menu. When I scroll through the page on my mobile device the menu disappears.

I attempt to make the menu sticky to the top and the menu will just disappears when user wanna close. Is there a way to keep the menu open until the link is clicked or the close menu button is clicked?

You can see it working live here : www.nhadatsonnghia.com

Any help would be really appreciated!!!

Thanks so much.

Here is my code :

```js
! function(n) {
    n.fn.menumaker = function(s) {
        var e = n(this),
            i = n.extend({
                title: "",
                format: "dropdown",
                sticky: !1
            }, s);
        return this.each(function() {
            return e.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + i.title + "</div>"), n(this).find("#menu-button").on("click", function() {
                n(this).toggleClass("menu-opened");
                var s = n(this).next("ul");
                s.hasClass("open") ? s.hide().removeClass("open") : (s.show().addClass("open"), "dropdown" === i.format && s.find("ul").show())
            }), e.find("li ul").parent().addClass("has-sub"), multiTg = function() {
                e.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>'), e.find(".submenu-button").on("click", function() {
                    n(this).toggleClass("submenu-opened"), n(this).siblings("ul").hasClass("open") ? n(this).siblings("ul").removeClass("open").hide() : n(this).siblings("ul").addClass("open").show()
                })
            }, "multitoggle" === i.format ? multiTg() : e.addClass("dropdown"), i.sticky === !0 && e.css("position", "fixed"), resizeFix = function() {
                n(window).width() > 768 && e.find("ul").show(), n(window).width() <= 768 && e.find("ul").hide().removeClass("open")
            }, resizeFix(), n(window).on("resize", resizeFix)
        })
    }
}(jQuery),
function(n) {
    n(document).ready(function() {
        n("#cssmenu").menumaker({
            title: "",
            format: "multitoggle"
        })
    })
}(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial:400,700); #cssmenu,#cssmenu &gt; ul,#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li,#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li a,#cssmenu #menu-button {display: block;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;list-style: none;padding: 0;}
#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu &gt; ul:after { content:&quot; .&quot; ; display:block; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0; height:0; }
#cssmenu #menu-button { display:none; }
#cssmenu {position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 15;float: right;}
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li {position: relative;vertical-align: middle;display: inline-block;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
#cssmenu.align-center &gt; ul { font-size:0; text-align:center; }
#cssmenu.align-center &gt; ul &gt; li { display:inline-block; float:none; }
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul { text-align:left; }
#cssmenu.align-right &gt; ul &gt; li { float:right; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li &gt; a {color: black;font-size: 16px;display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;letter-spacing: 1px;margin: 10px 0 0 0;padding: 0 12px;font-family: Open Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight: 500;line-height: 40px;}
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li:hover &gt; a { color:#ffffff;background: #ffbd2f;border:1px;border-radius:5px; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a { padding-right:10px; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:after { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:0; height:2px; display:block; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:before { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; display:block; width:2px; height:0; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; -webkit-transition:all .25s ease; -moz-transition:all .25s ease; -ms-transition:all .25s ease; -o-transition:all .25s ease; transition:all .25s ease; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub:hover &gt; a:before { top:23px; height:0; }
#cssmenu ul ul { position:absolute; left:-9999px; z-index:9999; }
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul { text-align:right; }
#cssmenu ul ul li { height:0; -webkit-transition:all .25s ease; -moz-transition:all .25s ease; -ms-transition:all .25s ease; -o-transition:all .25s ease; transition:all .25s ease;position: relative;list-style: none; }
#cssmenu ul ul ul li { height:0; -webkit-transition:all .25s ease; -moz-transition:all .25s ease; -ms-transition:all .25s ease; -o-transition:all .25s ease; transition:all .25s ease; }
#cssmenu li:hover &gt; ul { left:auto; }
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover &gt; ul { left:auto; right:0; }
#cssmenu li:hover &gt; ul &gt; li { height:35px; }
#cssmenu ul ul ul { margin-left:100%; top:0; }
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul { margin-left:0; margin-right:100%; }
#cssmenu ul ul li a { border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15); padding:15px; width:250px; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none; color:#dddddd; font-weight:400; background:#333333; }
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child &gt; a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item &gt; a { border-bottom:0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover &gt; a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover { color:#ffffff; }
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub &gt; a:after { position:absolute; top:16px; right:11px; width:8px; height:2px; display:block; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub &gt; a:after { right:auto; left:11px; }
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub &gt; a:before { position:absolute; top:13px; right:14px; display:block; width:2px; height:8px; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; -webkit-transition:all .25s ease; -moz-transition:all .25s ease; -ms-transition:all .25s ease; -o-transition:all .25s ease; transition:all .25s ease; }
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub &gt; a:before { right:auto; left:14px; }
#cssmenu ul ul &gt; li.has-sub:hover &gt; a:before { top:17px; height:0; }

@media all and (max-width:768px),only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (max-width:1024px),only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (max-width:1024px),only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1) and (max-width:1024px),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (max-width:1024px),only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi) and (max-width:1024px),only screen and (min-resolution:2dppx) and (max-width:1024px) {
#menu-desktop {float:left;background: #ffbd2f;padding: 0 5px;display: block;}
#cssmenu { width:100%; }
#cssmenu ul { width:100%; display:none; }
#cssmenu.align-center &gt; ul { text-align:left; }
#cssmenu ul li { width:100%; border-top:1px solid rgba(120,120,120,0.2); }
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover &gt; ul &gt; li { height:auto; }
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a { width:100%; border-bottom:0; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li { float:none; }
#cssmenu ul ul li a { padding-left:25px; }
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a { padding-left:35px; }
#cssmenu ul ul li a { color:#dddddd; background:none; }
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover &gt; a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active &gt; a { color:#ffffff; }
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul,#cssmenu.align-right ul ul { position:relative; left:0; width:100%; margin:0; text-align:left; }
#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:after,#cssmenu &gt; ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:before,#cssmenu ul ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:after,#cssmenu ul ul &gt; li.has-sub &gt; a:before { display:none; }
#cssmenu #menu-button { display:block; padding:32px; color:#dddddd; cursor:pointer; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:700; }
#cssmenu #menu-button:after { position:absolute; top:26px; right:13px; display:block; height:5px; width:40px; border-top:5px solid #ffffff; border-bottom:5px solid #ffffff; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu #menu-button:before { position:absolute; top:16px; right:13px; display:block; height:5px; width:40px; background:#ffffff; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after { top:23px; border:0; height:10px; width:40px; background:#ffffff; -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); -o-transform:rotate(45deg); transform:rotate(45deg); }
#cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before { top:23px; background:#ffffff;width:40px;height:10px; -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); -o-transform:rotate(-45deg); transform:rotate(-45deg); }
#cssmenu .submenu-button { position:absolute; z-index:99; right:0; top:0; display:block; border-left:1px solid rgba(120,120,120,0.2); height:46px; width:46px; cursor:pointer; }
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened { background:#262626; } #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button { height:34px; width:34px; }
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after { position:absolute; top:22px; right:19px; width:8px; height:2px; display:block; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after { top:15px; right:13px; }
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after { background:#ffffff; }
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before { position:absolute; top:19px; right:22px; display:block; width:2px; height:8px; background:#dddddd; content:&#39; &#39; ; }
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before { top:12px; right:16px; }
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<div id='menu-desktop'>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Đất Sơn Nghĩa</a></li>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Nhà Đất Gò Vấp</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Bán Nhà Gò Vấp mặt phố, mặt tiền</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Gò Vấp giá dưới 1 tỷ</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Gò Vấp giá 1 đến 2 tỷ</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Gò Vấp giá 2 đến 3 tỷ</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Gò Vấp giá 3 đến 4 tỷ</a></li>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Nhà Đất Gò Vấp bán theo phường</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Phường 8</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Phường 9</a></li>
  </ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>Nhà Đất Quận 12</a></li>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>Tin tức, tư vấn</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#' itemprop='url'>Kinh Nghiệm Mua Nhà</a></li>
<li><a href='#' itemprop='url'>Tin tức nhà đất</a></li>
<li><a href='#' itemprop='url'>Phong Thủy</a></li>
  </ul></li>
<li><a href='#' itemprop='url'>Liên hệ</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I see , my suggestion to you is just to write a additional class .show , which should be togglled on click event. And when user click on 'X' button , you should remove it .  In the class '.show' add this parameters :

```
#menu-desktop .show {
    background: #ffbd2f;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

This will gives you opportunities to handle mobile menu and user can see it all the time .

Of course if you don't want to hide all screen , then you can remove height property or add manually , other value.

Comment: Thank @MarinTerziyski but it doesn't work. I think the error occurred when resize in jquery, I tried the mobile mode on chrome when increasing and decreasing the browser height and the menu turned off. Can you see the jquery code for me?

Comment: I understand , try to remove this piece of code , wchich looking for resize event :

`resizeFix = function() {
                n(window).width() > 768 && e.find("ul").show(), n(window).width() <= 768 && e.find("ul").hide().removeClass("open")
            }, resizeFix(), n(window).on("resize", resizeFix)`  Try to add click event listeners to close and open menu , don't use resize .

Comment: Wow I think it works very well, thank @MarinTerziyski for taking the time to help me, have a nice day!